Laptop is not charging when plugged and very laggy
I accidentally connected a Lenovo charger to my Dell laptop. After I realized this, I disconnected and connected to its Dell charger but now it doesn't charge. The laptop still works when plugged in but not charging and very laggy. It works fine when using power from the battery only. What could be the reason? Did I damage the charging IC by connecting the wrong charger? The voltage rating of both the chargers is almost the same (19.5v and 20.5v)

Generally, plugging an incorrect charger into another device will not do significant damage. If the Lenovo charger is faulty/broken it may cause damage, but it's not normal for a charger that is working properly to damage something it is not intended for.

There are a lot of questions here about using wrong chargers. We cannot tell you precisely what happened to your laptop given the little information we have. A qualified local computer technician may be able to analyze your computer more precisely. https://superuser.com/search?q=wrong+charger

It could be the charging circuit was damaged, or it could be an issue with charging software/drivers. First, try to reset battery charging (look up directions for the specific model PC). If that does not work, then it needs professional repair.
